# nginx - another rewrite or internal redirection cycle - drupal

Tags: nginx, web-server, drupal, redirection

While migrating a site from another server, some strange problem occured.
I use the default configuration for all my drupal sites, but this one doesnt seem to work.
Some image files cause an internal server error - rewrite or internal redirection cycle.
The site does not have a domain, yet, so I am testing with the server ip, which should not be a problem.
When using this configuration for some default drupal installation, everything works fine. I also use memcached for static file caching, you can see that. As already mentioned, all of this should work properly.

This is my configuration:

```
server {
 server_name SERVERIP;
 root /var/www/;
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 index index.php;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/SERVERIP.access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/SERVERIP.error.log;

 if (-f $request_filename) {
 break;
 }

 # memcached
 location ~* \.(jpg|png|gif|js)$ {
 access_log off;
 expires max;
 set $memcached_key $uri;
 memcached_pass memcached;
 error_page 404 = @domain;
 }

 location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ @domain;
}

 location ~* ^.+.(htm|html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
 access_log off;
 expires max;
 root /var/www/;
 }

 location @domain {
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
 try_files $uri $uri/ @domain;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
 }
 }
```

I would be very glad if anyone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

regards

Comment: Is your memcache working right?

Comment: yes, it is. Even when I comment out these lines and let the server fetch each file normally, it doesnt work.

Comment: I think I got the confusing bit. When looking at the requests, some requests are sent as SERVERIP/sites/all/.../file.jpg and not like SERVERIP/SITEFOLDER/sites/all/.../file.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that, when using a domain name for the site, everything works correctly.
Maybe, the document root was just not set correctly or I messed something else up.
Also, some strange URL rewrites were active, which I had to turn off.